# Finding the dimensions of a rectangle in a photo, given knowledge of one side (perspective)

Tags: geometry

Consider a photograph of a table like this:

[image: Table]

Assuming the table is truly rectangular, and that the photograph was taken straight-on (that is, the near and far edges of the table are totally horizontal in the photo), and that I know the true length of one of the sides, how can I find the length of the other?

I can measure the pixels of each side, but how do I correct for perspective?

Comment: Just checking - you're looking for the true width/length from the true length/width?

Comment: The "vertical sides" meet at "visual infinity", so you have similar triangles.

Answer (score 1):

You need some other information, because the ratio between front and rear apparent widths depends only on the distance of the camera, while the ratio between real and apparent depth depends on the camera focal length and on its height with respect to rectangle plane.